# IdTcpServer cannot free its context thread after context.connection.disconnect() under CentOS+Lazarus

Tags: centos, lazarus, indy10

The result of Memo1 is still "ConnCnt:1" after I click btDisconn button, though I wait for several minutes.

But under windows xp it works fine, how can I make idtcpserver remove the invalid context thread?

Here's my code:

Client side (Windows7 + DelphiXE2 + Indy10.5.8):

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TcpClient.Host:=192.168.1.103;
  TcpClient.Port:=10000;
  TcpClient.Connect;
end;
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  try
    TcpClient.Disconnect;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Server side (Vmware + CentOS + Lararus1.0.12 + Indy10.5.8)

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var Bind:TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  TCPServer.Bindings.Clear;
  Bind:=TCPServer.Bindings.Add;
  Bind.IPVersion:=Id_IPv4;
  Bind.Port:=10000;
  TcpServer.OnExecute:=@TcpServerExecute;
  TcpServer.DefaultPort:=10000;
  TcpServer.Active:=true;
  Timer1.Interval:=5000;
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var CloseAction: TCloseAction);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=false;
  TcpServer.Active:=false;
end;

procedure TForm1.TcpServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var b:Byte;
begin
  try
    b:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte();
  except
    on E:Exception do memo1.Lines.Add('Error:'+E.Message)
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var lst:TList;
begin
  try
    lst:=TcpServer.Contexts.LockList();
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ConnCnt:'+inttostr(lst.Count));//the result is still ConnCnt:1 after i click btDisconn
  finally
    TcpServer.Contexts.UnlockList();
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btDisconnClick(Sender: TObject);
var i:Integer;lst:TList;itm:TIdContext;
begin
  try
    lst:=TcpServer.Contexts.LockList();
    for i:=0 to lst.Count-1 do begin
      itm:=TIdContext(lst.Items[i]);
      if Assigned(itm) then begin
        itm.Connection.Disconnect();
        itm.Connection.IOHandler.DiscardAll;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TcpServer.Contexts.UnlockList();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OT: move the lines `lst:=TcpServer.Contexts.LockList();` and `lst:=TcpServer.Contexts.LockList();` before `try` keyword.

Comment: Don't call `DiscardAll()` after calling `Disconnect()`, since the socket is now closed so it can't read any more data. If you just want to clear the `InputBuffer` then do so directly: `itm.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your server code that prevent it from shutting down correctly:

1. your `OnExecute` code is catching and discarding all exceptions and not allowing `TIdTCPServer` to process any of them. When `TIdTCPServer` is being deactivated, it closes all active sockets, which in turn causes current/subsequent socket operations to fail and raise exceptions. By discarding the exceptions, `TIdTCPServer` has no clue that the connections have been closed, and happily keeps calling the `OnExecute` event.  If you must catch exceptions (such as to log them), you need to re-raise any Indy-specific exceptions when you are done with them so `TIdTCPServer` can then process them.
2. you are accessing the `TMemo` in a thread-unsafe manner, which can (amongst other things) cause deadlocks.

Try this instead:

```
uses
  ..., IdSync;

type
  TMemoNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    FMsg: String;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    class procedure AddToMemo(const AMsg: string);
  end;

procedure TMemoNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(FMsg);
end;

class procedure TMemoNotify.AddToMemo(const AMsg: string);
begin
  with Create do
  begin
    FMsg := AMsg;
    Notify;
  end;
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., EIdException;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bind: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  TCPServer.Bindings.Clear;
  Bind := TCPServer.Bindings.Add;
  Bind.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  Bind.Port := 10000;
  TcpServer.OnExecute := TcpServerExecute;
  TcpServer.Active := True;
  Timer1.Interval := 5000;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var CloseAction: TCloseAction);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  TcpServer.Active := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.TcpServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  b: Byte;
begin
  try
    b := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      TMemoNotify.AddToMemo('Error:'+E.Message);
      if E is EIdException then raise;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  lst: TList;
begin
  lst := TcpServer.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ConnCnt:'+IntToStr(lst.Count));
  finally
    TcpServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btDisconnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  lst: TList;
begin
  lst := TcpServer.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for i := 0 to lst.Count-1 do
    begin
      try
        TIdContext(lst.Items[i]).Connection.Disconnect;
       except
       end;
    end;
  finally
    TcpServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively to re-raising Indy exceptions, you could just get rid of the exception handling in the `OnExecute` event altogether and use the `TIdTCPServer.OnException` event instead:

```
procedure TForm1.TcpServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  b: Byte;
begin
  b := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
  ...
end;

procedure TForm1.TcpServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  TMemoNotify.AddToMemo('Error:'+AException.Message);
end;
```